# Getting GraphX program to compile [c++] module command

Tags: command-line, compiling, c++

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux in general, and my professor has handed out a lab assignment for which the lab machines are already prepared for. I am trying to do this assignment on my laptop, but I am having some trouble trying to get my dev environment set up. The Professor included 3 files by the following names.

GraphX.o

GraphX.hpp

sample.cpp

**EDIT: See edit below before attempting to fix the below problem.**

He says that the following command will allow this to compile.

```
g++ GraphX.o -lx11 sample.cpp
```

I have all of the provided files in the correct directory but when I run this command I get the following message:

```
g++: error: ­-lX11: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT: I now understand that the correct command needs a capitol X. However, The command below still Confuses me.**

He then goes on to recommend the following command to fix the issue:

```
module add soft/gcc/4.9.2
```

but I only get the following output:

```
module: command not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: To build X11 client programs on Ubuntu, you will need to install the `libx11-dev` package. You will also need to make sure that you capitalize the library name correctly i.e. `-lX11` rather than `-lx11`.  However it's possible that the `GraphX.o` object code won't be compatible with objects compiled on your laptop.